# weka gives 100% correctly classified instances for every dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm not able to get accuracy, as every dataset I provide provides 100% accuracy for every classifier algorithm I apply. My data set is of 10 people. 
It gives the same accuracy for naive bayes, J48, JRip classifier algorithm.

[image]

```
+----+-------+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | name  | q1 | q2 | q3 | m1 | m2 | tut | fl | proj | fexam | total | grade |
+----+-------+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | abv   |  5 |  5 |  5 | 13 | 13 |   4 |  8 |    7 |    40 |   100 | p     |
|  2 | ca    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |   1 |  1 |    1 |    40 |    48 | f     |
|  3 | ga    |  4 |  2 |  3 |  5 | 10 |   4 |  5 |    6 |    20 |    59 | f     |
|  4 | ui    |  5 |  4 |  4 | 12 | 13 |   3 |  7 |    7 |    39 |    94 | p     |
|  5 | pa    |  4 |  1 |  1 |  4 |  3 |   2 |  4 |    5 |    22 |    46 | f     |
|  6 | la    |  2 |  3 |  1 |  1 |  2 |   0 |  4 |    2 |    11 |    26 | f     |
|  7 | ka    |  5 |  4 |  1 |  3 |  3 |   1 |  6 |    4 |    24 |    51 | f     |
|  8 | ma    |  5 |  3 |  3 |  9 |  8 |   4 |  8 |    0 |    20 |    60 | p     |
|  9 | ash   |  2 |  5 |  5 | 11 | 12 |   3 |  7 |    6 |    30 |    81 | p     |
| 10 | opo   |  4 |  2 |  1 | 13 |  1 |   3 |  7 |    3 |    35 |    69 | p     |
+----+-------+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to **not include any unique identifier column**.

Also **don't include the `total`**.

Most likely, the classifiers learned that "name" is a good predictor and/or that you need `total > 59` points total to pass.
I suggest you even withhold at least one exercise because of that - some classifiers will still learn that the sum of the individual points is necessary to pass.

I assume you want to find out if one part is most indicative of passing, i.e. "if you do well on part 3, you will likely pass". But to answer this question, you need to account for e.g. different amount of points per question, etc. - otherwise, your predictor will just identify which question has the most points...

Also, 10 is a much too small sample size!

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the output that is displayed that the tree that J48 generated used only the variable fl,  so I do not think that you have the problem that @Anony-Mousse referred to.

I notice that you are testing on the training set  (see the "Test Options" radio buttons at upper left of the GUI). That almost always overestimates the accuracy. What you are seeing is overfitting. Instead, use cross-validation to get a better estimate of the accuracy you could expect on new data. With only 10 data points, you should use either 10 folds or 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your model on cross-validation on "k splits" or Percentage split.

Generally in Percentage Split: Training set is of 2/3 of dataset and Test set is 1/3.

Also, What I feel that your dataset is very small... There are chances of high accuracy in that case.